# Splitting a list based on a another list (with elements treated together in order)

Tags: python, list

I am having two lists as:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
b = [4,5,6]
```

I am trying to split list `a` based on list `b` acting as a boundary condition, so that I can get two sublists as a *left* and *right* part of `a` as:

```
# left sublist 
[1,2,3]

# right sublist
[7,8,9,10]
```

---

Removing **b** from **a** is quite easy with,

```
filter(lambda x: x not in b, a)
```

or

```
list(set(a) - set(b))
```

**But how can I get the left and right remaining sublists?**

Comment: so the first array is sorted? and the order of elements from second array are the same in the first array?

Comment: Yes to both questions

Comment: The arrays being sorted isn't necessary if all you want to do is split the first array by the contents of the second.

Comment: You should edit your question and include the additional information, that the array is sorted and doesn't contain duplicate elements.

Answer (score 1):

If the first array is sorted you can use this to get left-hand list:

```
a[:a.index(b[0])]
```

and for the righthand list:

```
a[a.index(b[-1]) + 1:]
```

Comment: because the last element of b is on index(b[-1])

Comment: This doesn't cover a case where you have [1,2,3,3,4,5] and try and split on [3,4,5]. If the list has duplicates this will fail.

Comment: The lists will not contain any duplicates. Thanks for raising the question though

Comment: In case `b` is at the end of `a` you should check. It was only an easy solution check for possible exceptions. your welcome. @cbk200

Comment: @cbk200 @NaWeeD This only works if either `a` or `b` consist of consecutive numbers, otherwise the middle elements can vary e.g. a: [1,2,3,5,7,8], b: [3,4,7] would split up into [1,2], [8] incorrectly. See my answer for a generic solution.

Answer (score 1):

Generic solution (makes no assumptions about the arrays being sorted or having unique elements, works if the separator appears multiple times):

```
def array_split(arr, separator):
    result = [] # list of the sublists
    current_part = [] # current sublist we're assembling
    possible_separator = [] # store possible separator here (e.g. if the separator is 4,5,6 and we've got 4,5 so far)

    for i in arr:
        if i == separator[len(possible_separator)]: # matches next piece of separator?
            if len(possible_separator) == len(separator) - 1: # separator complete
                result.append(current_part)

                current_part = []
                possible_separator.clear()
            else: # add to possible separator
                possible_separator.append(i)
        else:
            current_part.extend(possible_separator) # wasn't the full separator, add to sublist and clear
            possible_separator.clear()

            current_part.append(i)

    result.append(current_part)
    return result
```

A pathological example:

```
array_split([1,2,3,4,5,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], [4,5,6]) == [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

This could also be trivially converted into a generator.

Answer (score 0):

In case the arrays are not sorted or duplicates are contained, one way would be to use a little bit of string magic: Convert both lists to strings (using a delimiter like `,` in between the numbers), split the first string with regard of the second split and after that, transform each string back to a list of integers. The code would be as such:

```
str_a = ",".join(map(lambda x: str(x), a))   # str_a = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10'
str_b = ",".join(map(lambda x: str(x), b))   # str_b = '4,5,6'

str_left, str_right = str_a.split(str_b)     # str_left = '1,2,3,'
                                             # str_right = ',7,8,9,10'

left = list(map(lambda x: int(x), str_left[:-1].split(','))) # [:-1] is there to get rid of the trailing ,
right = list(map(lambda x: int(x), str_right[1:].split(','))) # [1:] is there to get rid of leading ,
```

`left` and `right` are the two lists you want. I have to say though, this is an overkill. If no duplicates exists or arrays are always sorted, @NaWeeD's answer works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Generalized way to achieve this will be to create a function to firstly extract the index of the segments created due to your sublist in the base-list. And then *slicing* your base list based on those segments.

Here is the **sample generator to `yield` the segments created due to the sublist**:

```
def get_segment_index(base_list, sub_list):
    cursor, len_sub, len_base = 0, len(sub_list), len(base_list)
    for i in range(len_base-len_sub+1):
         if base_list[i:i+len_sub] == sub_list: # check for the match of sub-list
             yield cursor, i
             cursor = i+len_sub
    else:  # to yield the last segment
         if cursor != len_base:
             yield cursor, len_base
```

Now using above function within a *list comprehension*, you can get your desired segments with the help of *list slicing*. For example:

Sample run with **List Of Numbers**:

```
>>> a = [1, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 9, 7, 8, 10, 4, 5, 6, 9, 2]
#           ^  ^  ^                     ^  ^  ^
>>> b = [4,5,6]

>>> [a[x:y] for x, y in get_segment_index(a, b)]
[[1], [2, 3, 9, 7, 8, 10], [9, 2]]
```

Sample run with **List Of Strings**:

```
>>> a = ['I', 'am', 'sample', 'example', 'to', 'split', 'based', 'on', 'sample', 'example', 'sublist']
#                      ^          ^                                        ^         ^
>>> b = ['sample', 'example']

>>> [a[x:y] for x, y in get_segment_index(a, b)]
[['I', 'am'], ['to', 'split', 'based', 'on'], ['sublist']]
```

---

Since, you have only one occurrence of sublist, and you want left and right value, you may simply do:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> b = [4,5,6]

>>> left, right = [a[x:y] for x, y in get_segment_index(a, b)]

# Left sublist
>>> left
[1, 2, 3]

# Right sublist
>>> right
[7, 8, 9, 10]
```